# SizeLimitExceededException in LDAP request returning large number of objects

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-ldap

I need to update a large number of objects in LDAP. When I try to fetch them, I catch `org.springframework.ldap.SizeLimitExceededException`. How can I avoid this exception?

I tried to look for a paging solution, unfortunately the only one I found on the web is deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an LDAP client issues a search request and the number of entries that match the filter exceeds either the client-requested size limit or the size limit imposed on a client's authorization state, or the server has imposed some other limit on the number of entries that match the filter, the server must set the result code in the response to "size limit exceeded". Perhaps the Spring framework has bubbled the response code upwards.

Simple Paged Results are available when supported by the server, as well as Virtual List View.

For more information, see ["LDAP: Using ldapsearch"](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/), ["LDAP: Mastering search filters"](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/mastering-ldap-search-filters/), and ["LDAP: Programming Practices"](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/). Also, I have shared some technical LDAP notes related to resource limits being exceeded at my [website](http://www.ldapguru.info).